# Regex: dealing with unpredictable inputs: disallowed trailing (but otherwise OK) characters

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a regex that parses `<stock ticker> - <company>`. The problem is that the inputs are a little unpredictable and the formatting of allowed tickers is broad.

One hyphen in the interior of the ticker is OK, but it is not OK if the hyphen begins or ends the ticker. And more than one ticker is not allowed. So "BRK-B - Berkshire" should parse to "BRK-B" and "ALL- Allstate" should parse to "ALL". Additionally, the same rules for hyphens applies to periods.

A space should signify the end of the ticker.

Right now I'm using the regex `[a-zA-Z.-]*` with other checks to ensure that the data is properly formatted. It's really the trailing punction = bad (but if interior = OK) rule that's tripping me up. I don't know how to tell it that "ALL- Allstate" should be "ALL" but that "BRK-B - Berkshire" should be "BRK-B". I'm wondering if there is a single line regex that will do the above instead.

Comment: Can you post some examples of the data?

Comment: I think Kolink nailed it, but: "BRK-B - Berkshire" should parse to "BRK-B", "ALL- Allstate" should parse to "ALL". And so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
/[a-z](?:[a-z.-]*[a-z])?/i
```

This will force the first and last letters to be actual letters, and only allow `.` and `-` inside the word itself.

Comment: Maybe it's a matter of that I'm using Python re but that's returning "llstate" and "erkshire".

Comment: Ah, I guess it doesn't like the case-insensetive flag. Just add your `A-Z` back in (so `[a-zA-Z](?:[a-zA-Z.-]*[a-zA-Z])?`)

Comment: @Chris - Kolink is using Perl's special syntax for regular expressions. To use the case-insensitive flag in Python, pass in `re.I` as the `flags` argument: `re.compile(r"[a-z](?:[a-z.-]*[a-z])?", flags=re.I)`.

Comment: Thanks that seems to do the job, although it's not clear to me what it's doing and the documentation on `(?:...)` doesn't help. Why cant you just do something like `[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z.-]*[a-zA-Z])?` and leave out the `?:` part out?

Comment: @Chris - It's approximately equivalent to `r"([a-z])([a-z.-]*[a-z])?"` to split the string into two _groups_, and then accessing only the first group (`match.group(1)`).

Comment: @Chris You can drop the `?:` if you like. Al it does is make the group non-capturing rather than capturing. A captured group is returned later when performing matches, but here we just want a group without actually worrying about what's in that group - it's the entire match that matters. Using `?:` just saves a little time and memory.